# Check the first value of dynamically showing radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have radio buttons that changes values, depending on which option is selected on a dropdown list. I need the first value of every group of the radio buttons shown to be checked.

Here is the code:

```
$("#_ExampleList").change(function() {
            
            $('input[name="person.folderId"]:first').attr('checked', true).change();
            
            var allRadioDiv = $('.myRadio');
            allRadioDiv.each(function() {
                if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(this).children("input").each(function() {
                    $(this).prop("checked", true);
                        
                    });
                };
            });
var companyId = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            var radioFolders = $('#' + companyId);
            radioFolders.show();
        });
```

I tried to use

```
$('input[name="criterion.folderId"]:first').attr('checked', true).change();
```

but it checks the radiobutton only on the first option

```
<div id="<struts:property value='#company.id'/>" class="myRadio">
<struts:radio 
name="person.folderId" list="folders" listKey="id"
listValue="name" id="radioFolders" checked="true"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show html code as well?

Comment: I just added the html to the question

Comment: so there are mutliple `myRadio` div  which have radio-buttons inside it ?

Comment: yes, they are in an iterator, but are shown only the ones that are corresponding to the chosen option

Comment: can you try like this : `$('.myRadio  input[type=radio]:first').attr('checked', true)` ? or show your html generated code.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227543/discussion-between-dmnd00-and-swati).